# Make Gallery Slideshow Clickable on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have added images to the gallery to make it slideshow on my page. But would like to make each images clickable, I'm not sure if it is possible on wordpress.

I'm on blogspot before but I noticed that wordpress is more indemand today. But I also noticed that you can't code html and javascript in Wordpress unlike blogspot, it allows user to add html widget. Or am I wrong? Correct me and advise me if I am. I'm only new to wordpress though.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to code html and javascript in order to add functionality to wordpress. It's possible to make our own plugins, or code functions and hook them to the wordpress procedures. It's also possible to add filters to the output of existing functions from themes and plugins.

Javascript files can be enqueued but it's also possible to have php output javascript inline. Of course, these can be programmed to load only in specific sections of the site. Same goes for CSS.

There's a plugin called "Code Snippets" which allows to add code (js/php/html/css) globally or just in a certain page or post.

One can also edit the wordpress files directly but generally that's not a good idea.

I'm not sure what you desire when you say you want to make images clickable but you can check out this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/gallery-custom-links/

I believe that by default, wordpress creates a page for every media we upload and attach to a post/page, making it clickable, although users usually like to disable such default behavior to prevent visitor from straying.